# Libgdx packing a NinePatch into TextureAtlas

Tags: libgdx, nine-patch, texture-atlas

I have seen, that you can pack `NinePatch`es into `TextureAtlas` by using `TexturePacker2`. I have also seen [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/HowtoNinePatch). But i am not sure if understood it correct. I want to pack all my GUI-stuff into one `TextureAtlas` and my GUI-stuff is not only made of `NinePatch`s but also of some `TextureRegion`s. Is it possible to combine `NinePatch`s and `TextureRegion`s in one `TextureAtlas`? Can i use the deffault settings or do i have to make some custom settings like `paddingX`, `paddingY` in the `.JSON` file? And in my game can i load the `NinePatch` by using `atlas.createPatch("patchimagename");` or would it be better to safe everything as `TextureRegion`s and create the `NinePatch` out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets imagine you have that files structure you use for `TexturePacker2`:

```
images/
  image1.png
  image2-ninepatch.png   <-- this is NinePatch
  image3.png
```

Just change your extention of `NinePatch` files from `.png` (for example) to `.9.png` (and add 1px border to it, if needed).

```
images/
  ...
  image2-ninepatch.9.png
  ...
```

After this you could use `Skin` to wrap your textures and easly extract `NinePatch` and `TextureRegion` from `Atlas`:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = ... // load the Atlas
Skin skin = ... // create some root skin or use created one
skin.addRegion(atlas); // register atlas in skin
```

Furthermore, you could add many atlases to one skin!

Now you could do these:

1. Get `TextureRegion` by name:

   ```
   public TextureRegion getRegion(String region)
   {
       return skin.getRegion(region);
   }
   ```
2. Get `NinePatch` by name:

   ```
   public NinePatch getNinePatch(String region)
   {
       return skin.getPatch(region);
   }
   ```
3. Even use your images (`TextureRegion` or `NinePatch`) in your UI components (like button background etc) that use this skin.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: If i create it with this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html tool does it allready have the 1 px border? And do i need to define the stretchable areas ingame or in my skin.JSON?

Comment: @Springrbua, yes, this code will work with that tool. And no, you shouldn't define stretchable areas neither ingame and in JSON, because it's defined by 1px border already :)